# a question of local field

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a local field with mix char, $k$ residue field. We have an exact sequence

$0 \longrightarrow I \longrightarrow G_{K} \longrightarrow G_{k} \longrightarrow 0$

Then we obtain an action of $G_{k}$ on the abelization $I^{ab}$ of $I$. Let $T$ be the tame part of $I^{ab}$, and $F$ the frobinous element of $G_{k}$.

My question is

what is the action of $F$ on $T$?

Answer (score 4):

When $K$ is a local field with *finite* residue field $k$ of cardinality $q$, the maximal tamely ramified extension $M$ of $K$ contains the maximal unramified extension $N$ of $K$, the group $G=\mathrm{Gal}(N|K)$ (resp. $V=\mathrm{Gal}(M|N)$) is canonically isomorphic to $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$ (resp. the group of roots of $1$ of order prime to $q$), and the action of the generator $\sigma\in G$ on $V$ is "raising to the power $q$".

The original sources for all this are Chapter 16 of Hasse's *Number Theory* and a paper by Albert (*On $p$-ad­ic fields and ra­tion­al di­vi­sion al­geb­ras,* Ann. Math. (2) 41 : 3 (July 1940), pp. 674–​693). Iwasawa (*On Galois groups of local fields,*
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1955), 448–469) goes deeper into the question.  These two papers are easily available on the Web.

As you might find the sources a little difficult to follow, a simplification and clarification has conveniently appeared a few days ago [on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2580).  The authors start from scratch and work out many illustrative examples.  I hope you enjoy reading it.